# How can a function in a javascript hash call another one in the same hash safely

Tags: javascript, node.js, hashmap, ecmascript-6

Here is a javascript/ES6 method returning a hash consisting of two methods... writeA and _write. We want to call writeA from outside of the hash, and this method has itself to call _write, defined just below, to get its job done.

```
getHash = () => {
    return {
        writeA: () => {
            console.log(this);
            this._write('a');
        },
        _write: (value) => {
            console.log(value);
        }
    };
};

getHash().writeA();
```

When the last line gets executed, the interpreter says that this._write is not a function. _write has the same effect. How can I refer to _write from within writeA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `=>` for your function definitions, which completely changes the way `this` binding works. Functions created with `=>` are bound with `this` as what it was in the environment (scope) in which they were created. Since `getHash()` itself is an `=>` function, the value of `this` in the context where `getHash` is defined will be what's visible in `writeA()`.

If you go through the return value from `getHash()` and rewrite the functions with `function()` syntax, you'll get the behavior you expect.

Comment: It's a mistake to think that `=>` is just a convenient shorthand. It is that, but it has much more significant implications.

Comment: This answer is perfect... I will definitely read more about => and its implications. Thanks!

Comment: Good answer.  OP did save a few seconds typing a few characters.  Then spent minutes/hours fixing it.  Food for thought...

Comment: @RooSoft glad to have helped :)